# How to fix 'Ignoring clocale-0.0.4 because its extensions are not built'

Tags: ruby, macos, zsh

I am using rbenv to manage my ruby versions.

I have successfully installed colorls:

I have also installed clocale ( 0.0.4)

```
gem list

    *** LOCAL GEMS ***

addressable (2.8.0)
benchmark (default: 0.1.0)
bigdecimal (default: 2.0.0)
bundler (default: 2.1.4)
cgi (default: 0.1.0.1)
clocale (0.0.4) <-
colorls (1.4.6) <-
```

However when I launch my terminal I get the following message:

```
Ignoring clocale-0.0.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine clocale --version 0.0.4
Ignoring clocale-0.0.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine clocale --version 0.0.4

sudo gem pristine clocale -v 0.0.4

Restoring gems to pristine condition...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Restored clocale-0.0.4
```

But when I relaunch my terminal the same error message from above displays.

In my .zshrc I have the following to run colorls:

```
source $(dirname $(gem which colorls))/tab_complete.sh

alias lc='colorls -h --group-directories-first -1'

alias l='colorls --group-directories-first --almost-all'

alias ll='colorls --group-directories-first --almost-all --long'
```

Removing these lines removes the error message from the terminal.  It seems that colorls can't find the clocale gem even though they exist in the same directory.

I would greatly appreciate some assistance to get this up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out where the problem was coming from.

1. I had a copy of colorls and clocale under /Library/ruby/gems. I removed these copies.
2. I had to change the order of the following in my .zshrc file:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" <- must come before code below 
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)" <- must come before code below

eval "$(starship init zsh)"
source $(dirname $(gem which colorls))/tab_complete.sh

alias la='colorls -h --group-directories-first -1'
alias ld='colorls -d'
alias lf='colorls -f'

alias l='colorls --group-directories-first --almost-all'

alias ll='colorls --group-directories-first --almost-all --long'
```

Now the warning message is gone.